# How to generate the combination of numbers (Permutation and combination)

Tags: matlab, octave

I have the following 6 by 2 matrix:

```
1 9
2 3
5 6
8 7
3 4
5 1
```

I want to add any three numbers in each column using all possible combinations. I know that the total number of possible combinations in each column is 20, as I will be choosing 3 numbers from 6 numbers at any time (i.e 6 combination 3). So, I expect to have a 20 by 2 matrix as my output.

For instance, in column 1, if I add the numbers in the first 3 rows, I will get 8. Likewise, if I add the numbers in the first three rows in column 2 I will get 18. So my out in this case will be 8 18. Similarly, if I pick rows 2 to 4, my output will be 15 16, rows 3 to 5 will give 16 17. So will have something like:

```
8 18
15 16
16 17
  .
  .
etc
```

My final output would a 20 by 2 matrix.

Please, can anyone offer some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get indices for each unique combination and then use them as linear indices on your original matrix to get what you want as follows:

```
% your input matrix
A = [1, 9; 2, 3; 5, 6; 8, 7; 3, 4; 5, 1];

% find indices for unique combinations (i.e. order doesn't matter)
n = size(A,1);   B = zeros(nchoosek(n,3), 3);   counter = 0;
for i = 1 : n, for j = i+1 : n, for k = j+1 : n      
  counter = counter + 1;
  B(counter,:) = [i,j,k];
end; end; end

% apply as linear indices to original matrix and collect
C = [sum(A(B), 2), sum(A(B + size(A,1)), 2)]
```

```
C =
    8   18
   11   19
    6   16
    ⋮   ⋮
   13   11
   16   12
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Though, I am trying to understand the logic behind the code :)

Comment: If you'd like to understand what's happening in the last step a bit better, read the "Linear Indexing" and "Accessing Multiple Elements" paragraphs here: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html

Comment: I realised that when the data was increased to a 10 by 2 matrix the perms command did not work. for instance using the following data gave me errors: A = [1, 1; 1, 5; 3, 9; 4, 2; 4, 6; 6, 2; 7, 6; 6, 9; 9, 9; 4, 5];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122620/discussion-between-kola-and-tasos-papastylianou).

Comment: Thanks Tasos, you a very patient and thorough teacher. You are the best!

Comment: One does one's best when procrastinating away from a thesis. ^_^